# Block Comments in Logstash Config file

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, block-comments

I am just getting started with Logstash and wondering whether there is a way to specify block comments in logstash config file?
It will be very useful as I am testing with long grok patterns which span multiple lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently there is no block comments available . We have to go for single line comment only by using # at the start of line which you need to comment out.

Also comments can be used anywhere in the line

```
# this is a comment

input { # comments can appear at the end of a line, too
  # ...
}
```